# making node wait for db call to get completed

Tags: node.js, couchdb, couchdb-nano

I just started writing node.js code.

I'm writing a code that extracts data from a pdf file, cleans it up and stores it in a database (using couchdb and accessing that using nano library).

The problem is that the calls are being made asynchronously... so the database get calls (i make some get calls to get a few affiliation files during the clean up) get completed only after the program runs resulting in variables being undefined.  is there any way around this?

I've reproduced my code below

```
const fs = require('fs');

const os = require('os');

var couchDB = require('couch-db').CouchDB;

var pdf_table_extractor = require('pdf-table-extractor');

const filename = "PQ-PRI-0005-1806-01-0000_quoteSlipForLIBVIDGI1.pdf"

var nano = require('nano')('https://couchadmin:difficulttoguessmypassword@dbdev.perilwise.com');



var server = new couchDB('https://db.url.com');

server.auth("admin","admin");

var db = nano.db.use('pwfb');

var temp = [];

//New callView function
async function callView(){
try{

    const doc = await view('liabilitymdm','pi');
    for (var i =0; i<doc.rows.length;i++){
        tmp.push(doc.rows[i]);
    };
    return doc;
} catch(e){
    console.log(e);
};
```

};

```
function suc(result){
    let ttmp = [];
    console.log(result);
    var pageTables = result.pageTables;
    var firstPageTables = pageTables[0].tables;
    ttmp = callView();
    //this console log shows Promise { <pending> }
    console.log(ttmp)
    for (var k = 0; k < firstPageTables.length; k++) {
     var temp = firstPageTables[k];
     if (temp.length > 0) {
      dump.push(temp);
        }
    }
    // console.log(dump);
    var insurer = filename.substr(37,8);
    read_quote_slip(insurer,dump);
}


var read_quote_slip = (insurer,data) => {
    console.log("read_quote_slip correctly entered");
    var finOut = {};
    if (insurer === "LIBVIDGI"){
        finOut.insurer = insurer;
        finOut.policyType = data[2][0].replace(/Quotation  for/g,"");
        finOut.natureOfWork = data[13][3];
        let dedpos = indexGetter(data, "Deductible")[0];
        finOut.deductible = data[dedpos+1][0];
        let cov = indexGetter(data, "Coverage Territory and Jurisdiction")[0];
        finOut.coverageTerritory = data[cov+1][0].replace(/Territory/g,"");
        finOut.coverageJurisdiction = data[cov+2][0].replace(/Jurisdiction/g,"");
        let ext = indexGetter(data,"Extensions")[0];
        finOut.coverage = data[ext+1][0].split(/\r?\n/);
        let majexc = indexGetter(data,"Major Exclusions")[0];
        finOut.exclusions = data[majexc+1][0].split(/\r?\n/);
        let prdtl = indexGetter(data,"Description")[0];
        let prm = premiumcompute(data,prdtl,dedpos);
        finOut.premium = prm;
        finCleaned = libvidgi_cleaned(finOut);
        // console.log(finCleaned);
    }
}

var indexGetter = (words,toFind) => {
    var finindex = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        for (var j = 0; j < words[i].length; j++){
            if(words[i][j].indexOf(toFind) >=0 ){
                finindex.push(i);

    }
  }
}
    return finindex;
}


var premiumcompute = (data, from, to) => {
    let finprem = [];
    let numbop = to - from - 2;
    let incr = 0;
    for (var i = from+2; i < to; i++){
        let pr = {};
        pr.option = incr+1;
        pr.sumInsured = data[i][2].replace(/ /g,"");
        pr.premium = data[i][data[i].length - 1].replace(/ /g,"");
        finprem.push(pr);
        incr +=1;
    }
    return finprem;
}


var libvidgi_cleaned = (finOut) => {

    return finOut;

}

var fal = (result) => {
    console.log(result);
    console.log("there was an error");
}


var readPDFFile = function(filename){
    //Decide which insurer from the filename
    // console.log(filename);
    console.log(filename.substr(37,8)+"Printed on line 38");
    insurer = filename.substr(37,8)
    pdf_table_extractor(filename, (result) => {suc(result)} , fal);

    }



var libvidgi_data_extract = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    let arr = data.pageTables.tables;
    for (var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++ ){
        console.log(arr[i]);
    }
}

readPDFFile(filename);
```

Comment: It's kind of difficult to help since you attached A LOT of code. It is recommended to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, you mentioned some variables are undefined - which ones? You should highlight that in your examples.

Comment: Sorry.  this is basically a trial code that I've been writing... callView is the function that calls the view and it goes into suc (which is called by pdf_table_extractor).  Bascially i'm trying to get the pdf contents read onto a variable...the code works if i put the output into a text file

Comment: Ive gone ahead and removed all the excess code

Comment: It would help if you pointed out where the problem is exactly. Which variables are undefined? I would use comments in the code to highlight that.

Comment: Ive added the relevant console logs

Comment: within callView, one console log works while the console log outside the db.view() gives me a blank array.  My takeaway is that the db calls are being run asynchronously and hence the delay is causing node to run the other lines first.... how do I get node to run this function synchronously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This answer assumes you are using Node.js > v7.6**

Since `db.view` accepts a callback, and you wish to wait for it to finish, one solution will be to `promisify` it - meaning to turn it into a `promise` which can be `awaited`. You can use a library like [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html) or you can even use Node's builtin [promisify](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) util. Then you can rewrite `callViews`:

```
const {promisify} = require('util');

const view = promisify(db.view);

async function callView() {
    try {
        const doc = await view('liabilitymdm', 'pi');
        // the async operation is now guaranteed to be done
        // (if there is an error it will be caught by the catch clause)
        for (var i = 0; i < doc.rows.length; i++) {
            temp.push(doc.rows[i]);
        }
        console.log(temp);
    } catch (e) {

    }
}
```

**If you are not using Node.js > v7.6** (and cannot use `async\await` you can still utilize promises, by using their `then` method:

```
const {promisify} = require('util');

const view = promisify(db.view);

function callView() {
    view('liabilitymdm', 'pi')
        .then(doc => {
            for (var i = 0; i < doc.rows.length; i++) {
                temp.push(doc.rows[i]);
            }
            console.log(temp);
            return temp;
        })
        .then(temp => {
            console.log(temp);
        })
        .catch(e => {});
}
```

Notice how the first `then` is returning something which is used in a later `then`.

Comment: why do you use const {promisify} in the declaration?  Is it different from const promisify = ?

Comment: @galeej It's called [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring). It's not required for your issue, you can replace it with `const promisify = require('util').promisify`.

Comment: i modified the callView function as per your instructions.  the console log works now, however, when i call the variable in the line after callView, I am getting promise(<pending>) as an output.  is that normal? I've added console logs in the program

Comment: Since `callView` now returns a promise, you need to `await` it or `.then` it. If you are used to working with callbacks and are not familiar with promises, you probably have to redesign a lot of your code. In my opinion - for the long run it will be good for you. I suggest you read some articles about promises before diving in...

Comment: Understood.  So basically every function that needs to access callView should be an async function if I am using await correct?

Answer (score 1):

To make Node run asynchronously, you can use the keywords `async` and `await`.
They work like this:

```
async function doSomething () {
    const formattedData = formatData();
    const result = await db.postToDatabase(formattedData);
    // the below will not happen until the above line is finished
    doSomethingElse(result);
}
```

It's pretty simple in Node to get functions to execute asynchronously. Just put the `async` keyword at the beginning of the function definition and then put `await` in front of anything that you want to block execution until completed.